# Unpredictable behavior onStart() onPause() and onResume()

Tags: android

I have break points setup on the super's of onStart, onPause, and onResume in multiple
activities. I want to handle the back button being pressed and instead of going back to the main activity I am trying to get my program to goto the last activity before the back button.

When playing around in debug mode and following these three functions calls I am finding that they are unpredictable. When a choice is made to advance to another activity the activity I was in has its onResume() called where I thought onPause() would be called and after onResume(), onStop() is called.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".CountrySelection"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".StateSelection"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".CitySelection"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".CategorySelection"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".SubCategorySelection"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayAdsActivity"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayAdActivity"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".SavedAdsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

</application>

    case R.id.locationbutton:{

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("Locations",continents);
            i.setClass(this,CountrySelection.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            break;

        }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    location = position;
    i.putExtra("States",continents.get(position).getStates());
    i.setClass(this, StateSelection.class);
    startActivityForResult(i,0);


}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("Cities",states.get(position).getCounties());
    i.setClass(this, CitySelection.class);
    startActivityForResult(i,0);

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the last activity before the back button"?

Comment: @njzk2 I have an activity I call from my main activity with startActivityForResult(intent).. From that next activity there is 3 more activities started and say the user made a choice selection on the 2nd he did not like and wants to go back from the third to the 2nd, right now my program goes right back to the main activity. I want the user to be able to go back to the 2nd activity  after hitting the back button

Comment: your problem is that your activities do not enter the activity stack correctly. can you paste the manifest (the part where you declare the activities)?

Comment: taht is weird. When you start an activity from another one, the new activity is put on the activities stack, until back is pressed (or until some other behavior tempers with said stack). You are not modifying the activities stack are you?

Comment: @njzk2 I am not modifying the activity stack that I am aware of. I am making a call to startActivityForResult() from MainActivity and then calling subsequent activities to achieve final result. I am not doing anything fancy within those activities. I am just loading the listview w/ content and using the onItemClickListener to return selection.

Comment: and by "calling subsequent activities" you mean by "startActivity", right?

Comment: @njzk2 I am using startActivityForResult() in subsequent activities also... dang..might be my problem, ha?

Comment: don't think so. startActivityForResult should basically have the same behavior, with a result. However, here is a lead: i guess you call finish() in your onActivityResult.

Comment: @njzk2 I do..and have read about it and think I understand what is going on now...thats whats calling the onStop() in the lifecycle and kicking it back to the mainactivity.. I am guessing from my readings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29) which describes how to set flags on your Intent to define how they should (or should not) go on the stack?

By default, when you have a chain of activities being called, the last one should be shown when hitting the back key. Can you post some code to show us how your calling your other activities?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in your onActivityResult, you must check the actual result.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    // The user pressed back, don't do anything
} else {
    // the user did not pressed back, you can finish:
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
```